# kubectl proxyconnect timeout when run almost any command

Tags: kubernetes

i have an issue when i want to run almost any command kubectl.
the message is: **Unable to connect to the server: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 16.85.88.10:8088: i/o timeout**

can thaat proxy be changed

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after 2 min from the post i found by myself the solution using no_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,localdomain.com,Yourdomain.com, mast.yourdomain.com"

Thanks,
Alin.